Schengen visa application for Iceland
I am from Nigeria and I want to submit my Schengen visa application for Iceland, I do not have a family there and I want to go there for say a tour/ visiting some companies to discuss business matters, I can book my hotel reservation, but from all I see online here, they are insisting on a letter of invitation.
I have an intent to visit for tourism purposes and the intent is to go for a business exploration purposes at the beginning of the year, and using the same avenue to check out companies I can import solar batteries as well as solar panels, etc. from.
Now this is what I plan on writing for them as a letter of intent / letter of introduction (as an entrepreneur), is this some very good example to start with, judging the fact that I do not have any one to meet with at this time, or is it better I book a tour instead, then use the same guise to approach these companies and check the pricing of everything in this regard.
Can I have it that, I want to come for Tourist purposes and at the same time, seek business resources in Iceland, and if possible register my company in Iceland for easy access and access to imports and export business, etc?

This isn’t quite a concise question, and I’m afraid it just looks like you are trying to find a pretext to get a Schengen visa.
You don’t decide you want to get a Schengen visa and then try to find out what story would work best.
It’s the other way around.
You have a good and valid reason to visit a specific country, and then you try to get a visa on that basis.
Tourism is one thing. Business is another. While you could do both in a single trip, at least one of the two must stand on its own feet, and at this time neither does.
Your whole business thing is just convoluted and even we see through it, so a trained consular officer is just going to reach directly for the “refused” button in less than 5 minutes (probably a lot less). Remember that contrary to the UK they don’t even have to write a page or two to explain why. They just tick boxes. I can already tell you they are going to tick one of reasons #2, #8 and #9 (probably several). Maybe also #3.
Do you even have a business? A sales network? Funds to buy the hardware, pay for shipping, duties and taxes? Have you even tried to find a single supplier in the country? Why don’t you contact them by e-mail or phone? Are you planning to just knock on doors? Can you even list one supplier? Why Iceland if you don’t have anybody lined up? Why Iceland when it’s one of the smallest countries in the Schengen Area? Why would you even consider buying from there when it’s probably cheaper to buy from China or other countries?
Oh, you don’t really have a business yet, you want to set one up in Iceland? Why Iceland? Do you have funds or investors? Do you have any local contacts? Do you know the language?
It just doesn’t add up. And you probably don’t have half of the paperwork required.
Remember that a visa is not a right. You have to convince them that:

You have a legitimate reason to visit (nope)
You have the funds to support yourself during your stay and pay for your travel back home (don’t know but somehow I doubt it).
You have a good reason to travel back home and will actually do so before your visa expires (ditto, especially with the "I want to set up a company in Iceland" bit).

Convince them as in provide evidence. As in company registration, bank statements, tax returns, pay slips, information about your business, etc.
Remember also that:

The "richer" the country, the more difficult they are. Iceland and Norway (which process the visa applications for Iceland for Nigeria) are among the richest countries in the Schengen Area (they're actually both in the top 10 worldwide)
Nigeria is in the top 15 countries with the highest Schengen visa refusal rate (over 40%).

Do yourself a favour. Forget about the Schengen Area or any similar country for now. If you really want to do business, you can do it from wherever you are nowadays. You can sign contracts without even seeing a client in person. But you’ll need to have a real business to do that. And it’s probably much easier to start one in your own country rather than halfway around the world in a country using a different language.
Once you have a real business, getting a visa to go visit actual suppliers or customers is just going to be natural. Because it’s the right way around.

point taken, i have several visits in and out stamps of several nations, can this do any good?

@Keros That can help if they are for "difficult" countries (mostly those which require a visa) like those of the Schengen Area, the UK, the US, Canada, Australia, etc. If they are for neighbouring countries with about the same socio-economic development and visa-free access, then no, it doesn't matter much. But in any case that doesn't change the need for a well documented legitimate purpose for your visit.

Like i said, I have a company, instead of the normal 2 way thing (Tourism / Business) to complicate issues, i think saying i am going for a Sabbatical Leave works and focus squarely on the tourist aspect, then i can do other stuff like making enquiries and visiting if need be, but not working on a visit visa which i do not even intend to do, what do you think of this?

@Keros ..,what do you think of this? As the two existing answers state, if you have a valid premise for the trip (you seem to have decided on tourism), and you can prove you meet the eligibility criteria including intention to leave, then go for it. The only way to find out is to apply.

@Keros In all cases it's still a visitor visa, and you are still trying to invent a reason to get a visa rather than actually having a reason. What is your actual, real, truthful reason for wanting to visit Iceland? And no, it's obviously not tourism, and it's clearly not business.

@Traveller, thank you.

@jcaron, its visit. Then if i like what i see, i can switch to business. This is what i wanted you to understand, So i needed to be very clear as regards what i am doing.

@Keros "visit" is not a reason. All visitors visit. If you mean tourism, then it's tourism. But tourism means you need to prove you can (easily) afford the trip (you have the money to cover the whole cost, the cost of the trip is not very high compared to your income...) and that you have a good reason to go back (so called "ties to your home country"), like a stable, well-paid job, family, property, employees, etc. Well-paid must be taken in the context of the country you are visiting. See my previous answer to your previous question

@jcaron, its properly understood. I thank you for your clarifications.

@Keros Why, out of all the Schengen / other countries you could choose, have you picked Iceland to visit? It’s a long way from Nigeria, it’s expensive, no matter the time of year you will need the kind of warm clothing you probably don’t own given Nigeria’s climate. Have you costed the proposed trip? Can you show that it is easily affordable?

You will first need to figure out what, exactly, you want to do and why you want to go to Iceland specifically to do it.
If you want to be a tourist in Iceland, then you need to have a tourist itinerary and the funds to support it.
if you have business reasons to be in Iceland, then you need an invitation from an established company in Iceland.
As an aside, trying to do any kind of solar energy business in Iceland seems like quite the challenge, it's a famously cloudy and cold place that also has abundant hydropower and geothermal energy.

Reykjavik currently has about 4 hours of daylight (if you want to call it that) :-)

@Hilmar but consider the figure on June 19th, which is about 21 hours.

@phoog The problem is that it's currently quite difficult to store electrical energy captured in the summer to use it during the winter (when you most need it) ... And most importantly, latitude does not only have an effect on the amplitude of daytime variations (the yearly average is of course the same everywhere), but also on the incidence angle, which greatly affects irradiance.
